# "For the/a Xth year running in..." meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

*Years running* means *consecutive years.* No problem with that. But I saw it is used in sentences like:

> 1. That helps explain why Greece probably beat its primary budget target ***for a fourth year running in 2018***.
> 2. There was a shortfall in zinc production ***for the second year running in 1996***.

To my understanding:

> Sentence 1. **Greece beat its primary budget target in the last three years, and do the same in the 2018 which is the fourth year.**
>
> 2. **There was a shortfall in zinc production in 1995 and in 1996 too which is the second year.**

As far as I understand that's the sense that it gives but I can not be sure.

Comment: Your understanding it right.

Answer (score 1):

This is adjectival meaning 3.1 from the [Oxford English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/running):

> (postpositive) Consecutive; in succession.
>   "he failed to produce an essay for the third week running"

It's the same meaning as "for the third consecutive week" or "for the third successive week".